# Как сконфигурировать webpack dev server в Laravel приложении?

Tags: laravel, webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server

Есть удаленная машина на которой находится *Laravel* приложение, на локальную машину я выкачал проект и синхронизировал его по `SFTP`.

Первый вопрос, это где нужно запускать `Dev` сборку `Webpack` (На локалке или на сервере) и как вообще правильнее? Если на локальной машине то как проксироваться к серверу c Backend.

Я без проблем смог сделать так, чтобы запуская сборку получить все прелести HMR, но в директории `public/index.html`, но я не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы `webpack-dev-server` работал с `PHP`, например `myapp.com/tasks`?

Comment: `Dev` - это там где разработка ведется. `Prod` - это там где юзеры пользуются плодами, разработки. В идеале, есть ещё `Stage` - это там где всё как в проде, но юзеры туда не допускаются, тестовый сервер, перед диплоем в прод. Когда всё готово рабочий код диплоится на прод (или если есть стейдж, то на стейдж).

Comment: Подскажи, ты используешь laravel mix или другой шаблон webpack?

Comment: Долго боролся с голым конфигом вебпака, но всетаки настроил все через laravel-mix, все превосходно работает включая HMR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, в своем проекте я не использовал `laravel-mix`, т.к. мне нужна была бОльшая гибкость настройки самого webpack (Мне нужны были асинхронные компоненты Vue вместе с HMR, а асинхронные компоненты лучше использовать с родным `webpack dev server` вместо browserSync). Я также не являюсь гуру webpack.

#### webpack

Итак, webpack запускает свой сервер на localhost (на локальном компе)
В настройках webpack.config в объект `devServer` нужно добавить следующий `middleware`, который разрешает cors, т.к. к дев серверу будут кроссдоменные запросы (сервер на localhost, а проект на другом домене).

```
/**
 * https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-before
 * @param app - Express app
 */
before: function(app) {
  // Добавляем промежуточный обработчик 
  // всех GET запросов к webpack devServer
  app.get("*",function (req, res, next) {
    // console.log(req.headers)
    res.set({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': req.headers.origin,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'
    });
    next()
  })
},
```

А теперь объяснение. В связи с жесткой CORS политикой браузеров сервер, к которому браузер обращается с другого домена, должен прислать как минимум два заголовка:

> - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
> - `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`

Причем недостаточно выдать заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` со значением `*` (все домены). Нужно отдать заголовок с конкретным доменом,
Например, вы с домена `http://example.com` обращаетесь к `http://localhost:8080`, так сервер `http://localhost:8080` должен в ответе отдать два вышеуказанных заголовка, причем заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` должен иметь значение `http://example.com`.
Также сделует помнить, что localhost у вас по http протоколу работает, поэтому, если собираетесь так вести разработку на `https://example.com`, то ничего не выйдет (опять же политика безопасности браузеров)

#### laravel

тут немного проще. В режиме разработки webpack сборку именует `app.js` (Опять же laravel mix не использовал, там не знаю тонкостей, возможно знающие дополнят ответ)
В шаблоне `blade`, который относится к нужному роуту, вывожу `<script src="http://localhost:8080/app.js"></script>` по условию наличия GET параметра debug вместо стандартных скриптов и стилей

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>
    @if(!$isDev)
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
    @endif
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <example></example>
    </div>
    @if(!$isDev)
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    @else
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/app.js"></script>
    @endif
  </body>
</html>
```

Это все упрощенно, в реале моя конфигурация несколько сложнее

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!)))